# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup only scrapes the first page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** some data from the webmd messageboard. Initially I constructed a loop to get the page numbers for each category and stored the in a dataframe. When I try to run the loop I do get the proper amount of post for each subcategory but only for the first page. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

```
lists2=[]
df1= pd.DataFrame (columns=['page'],data=page_links)
for j in range(len(df1)):
   pages = (df1.page.iloc[j])
   print(pages)
   req1 = urllib.request.Request(pages, headers=headers)
   resp1 = urllib.request.urlopen(req1)
   soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp1,'lxml')
   for body_links in soup1.find_all('div',class_="thread-detail"):
       body= body_links.a.get('href')
       lists2.append(body)
```

I am getting the proper page in the print function but then it seem to iterate only in the first page and getting the links of the posts. Also when I copy and paste the link for any page besides the first one it seems to momentarily load the first page and then goes to the proper number page. I tried to add `time.sleep(1)` but does not work. Another thing I tried was to add `{headers='Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=notimportant'}`

Comment: You'll want to create some sort of recursive function that's aware of the pagination links - [I've only ever done this with pyquery](https://gist.github.com/JKirchartz/05b1132a1151bb497bb408fdf4d0cc56)

Comment: with `requests` you can use `Session` which will get `PHPSESSID` (and other cookies) from server when you do first `GET` request, and it will add it to all other `GET`/`POST` requests automatically.

Comment: why don't you use `for url in page_links:`. You don't need `DataFrame` for this. And if you need `DataFrame` then `for url in df1['page']:`

Comment: @furas How would I implement this?

Comment: as for me your problem is not in `DataFrame`  but in `find_all` - it seems only one page has `<div class_="thread-detail">` in HTML so it can't get elements from other pages.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
pages = (df1.page.iloc[j])
```

With this:

```
pages = (df1.page.iloc[j, 0])
```

You will now iterate through the values of your DataFrame

Comment: Iterating through the dataframe doesn't seem to be the problem. Also this would return an error.

Answer (score 0):

If `page_links` is list with urls like

```
page_links = ["http://...", "http://...", "http://...", ]
```

then you could use it directly

```
for url in page_links:
    req1 = urllib.request.Request(url headers=headers)
```

If you need it in DataFrame then

```
for url in df1['page']:
    req1 = urllib.request.Request(url headers=headers)
```

But if your current code displays all urls but you get result only for one page then problem is not in `DataFrame` but in `HTML` and `find_all`.

It seems only first page has `<div class_="thread-detail">` so it can't find it on other pages and it can't add it to list. You should check it again. For other pages you may need different arguments in `find_all`. But without urls to these pages we can't check it and we can't help more.

It can be other common problem - page may use `JavaScript` to add these elements but `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript - and then you woould need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript. You could turn off JavaScript in browser and open urls to check if you can see elements on page and in HTML in`DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox.

---

As for `PHPSESSID` with `requests` you could use `Session` to get from server fresh cookies with `PHPSESSID` and automatically add them to other reuqests

```
import requests

s = reqeusts.Session()

# get any page to get fresh cookies from server
r = s.get('http://your-domain/main-page.html')

# use it automatically with cookies
for url in page_links:
    r = s.get(url)
```